# Just Want to Fire a Server Side Button Click(Hidden button) Event From javaScript, Tried Most of the Techniques nothing is Working

Tags: c#, javascript

i tried Like This.

```
     1. document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnHidden1").click();

     2.            __doPostBack('<%= btnHidden1.ClientID %>', 'OnClick');

     3.   document.getElementById("<%= btnHidden1.ClientID %>").click();

     4.   $('btnHidden1').trigger('click'); 

     5. var Btn = document.getElementById("<%= btnHidden1.ClientID %>");

        Btn.click();
```

How Shal i do i., Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "btnHidden1" is an id, you can do this with jquery:

```
$('#btnHidden1').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on how you hide the button. Some browsers don't allow 'hidden' elements to be clicked if they are 'display:none' or 'opacity:0' or 'visibility:hidden'.

Using 'position:absolute;' and moving the button off the page with 'left:-999px' might solve the problem.